# Control a Select with Div Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select with a few option, generated from php.
I want to get all the option text and create an equal amount of div with the text.
On each div click the select option should change to the corresponding one.

**[Not working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1j81w1q5/)**

```js
$("select option").each(function() {
    var text = $( "select option" ).text();
    $("#sizes").append("<h1>" + text + "</h1>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sizes"></div>
<select id="attribute155" class="super-attribute-select">
  <option value="197" price="0">XS</option>
  <option value="198" price="0">S</option>
  <option value="199" price="0">M</option>
  <option value="200" price="0">L</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to get all the option text and create an equal amount of div with the text

You should use current object `$( this )` that refer to the current option in `each()` instead of `$( "select option" ).text()` that will return always the first option text :

```
var text = $( this ).text();
```

> On each div click the select option should change to the corresponding one.

Store the value of every option in the correspanding `h1` using `data-*` attributes :

```
$("#sizes").append("<h1 data-value='" + value + "'>" + text + "</h1>");
________________________^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then attach a click event to the `h1` elements that get the stored value from data attribute using `.data()` and select the correspending `option` :

```
$('body').on('click', '#sizes h1', function() {
    var value = $( this ).data('value');
    $("select").val(value).change();
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("select option").each(function() {
    var text = $( this ).text();
    var value = $( this ).val();
  
    $("#sizes").append("<h1 data-value='" + value + "'>" + text + "</h1>")
});

$('body').on('click', '#sizes h1', function() {
    var value = $( this ).data('value');
    $("select").val(value).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sizes"></div>
<select id="attribute155" class="super-attribute-select">
  <option value="197" price="0">XS</option>
  <option value="198" price="0">S</option>
  <option value="199" price="0">M</option>
  <option value="200" price="0">L</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this will return select instance @Zakaria Acharki

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Thanks @anshu for yout intervention.. updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
*$("select").change(function(e) {
    var text = $( e.target ).find(":selected").text();
    $("#sizes").append("<h1>" + text + "</h1>")
});*

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sizes"></div>
<select id="attribute155" class="super-attribute-select">
  <option value="197" price="0">XS</option>
  <option value="198" price="0">S</option>
  <option value="199" price="0">M</option>
  <option value="200" price="0">L</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated your fiddle, [**Working fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/1j81w1q5/1/) , now your select options will be appended to the `div` as `h1`s and also when you click on the h1 tags the corresponding value will be set in the select element.

i guess that was the question.

As a side note , i am comparing the values using `.text()` method of jquery .

```js
$("select option").each(function() {
    var text = $( this ).text();
    $("#sizes").append("<h1>" + text + "</h1>")
});

$("#sizes>h1").click(function(event) {

  var h1elemval = $(event.currentTarget).text();
  //alert(h1elemval);
  $("#attribute155 option").each(function(index, item) {
    item.selected = false;

    if ($(item).text() === h1elemval) {
    //  console.log($(item).text());
      item.selected = true;
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sizes"></div>
<select id="attribute155" class="super-attribute-select">
  <option value="197" price="0">XS</option>
  <option value="198" price="0">S</option>
  <option value="199" price="0">M</option>
  <option value="200" price="0">L</option>
</select>
```